# app is sending multiple notifications

Tags: ios, xcode

I want my app to send a single notification at a given time and repeat daily. The notification sends fine but it sends multiple notifications. So instead of sending 1, it sends 5. How can I fix this with code. I have 2 viewcontrollers if that is meaningful.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    // ask for permission for notifications
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .sound], completionHandler: {didAllow, error in
        })
  // making the content of the notification 
    let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
    let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
    content.title = "Get Motivated"
    content.body = "Need Some Motivation? We've Got Plenty!"
    content.sound = UNNotificationSound.default()

    //triggering notification 
    var dateComponents = DateComponents()
    dateComponents.hour = 13
    dateComponents.minute = 35
    let trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: dateComponents, repeats: true)

    let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: UUID().uuidString, content: content, trigger: trigger)
    center.add(request)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a little hard to be precise without seeing more of your code so forgive me if I misunderstood something. Nevertheless, here are some suggestions:

You are sending notifications every time your view controller's "viewDidLoad" method is called. For a bit of context, in earlier versions of iOS, in order to save memory, views were unloaded from memory when views were removed from view hierarchy (say, after a transition to a different full screen view); it is not done anymore, but "viewDidLoad" is not guaranteed to be called only once during the life time of a given view controller. In addition to that, if you instantiate and present a view controller of this class more than once, "viewDidLoad" will be called multiple times.

Your code, also, does not seem to take into account a possibility that the app might be launched more than once.

In order to ensure that only one notification is scheduled, you can:

1. Check for already scheduled notifications and see if the one you are trying to add is a duplicate (you can use [UNUserNotificationCenter.getPendingNotificationRequestsWithCompletionHandler](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/unusernotificationcenter/1649513-getpendingnotificationrequestswi?language=swift) method for that);
2. Remove all already scheduled notifications and add new ones in their place (see [UNUserNotificationCenter.removeAllPendingNotificationRequests](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/unusernotificationcenter/1649509-removeallpendingnotificationrequ?language=swift)).

The method you choose, of course, depends on the logic of your app.

Good luck!

Comment: removing all pending notifications worked. I then put the notification in after that. Thank you